# How to update react-dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown) inside a component I made. how can I update/refresh/reload it (the dropdown, not the component) when a state property of the component changes?

Comment: Pass `options` as `props` from parent component.

Comment: can you provide an example please?

Comment: You would have to post your code attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should simply be accomplished by passing the array of dropdown values as a prop to the `options` value.

```js
<Select
 value={this.state.releaseFilter}
 onChange={this.handleDropdownChange}
 options={this.state.dropdownArray}
 className='release-dropdown'
 placeholder="Select A Release"
/>
```

As long as that component re-renders, the dropdown options should refresh.